Binding different lists to different rows in WPF DataGrid
I am writing a WPF application (not using MVVM yet) and am trying to bind different list to different row in DataGrid.
I have 2 lists:
private List<string> roundProfileTypeNames;
private List<string> rectProfileTypeNames;

and I have a DataGrid as follows:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Each row contains a profile name + a checkbox which is checked if profile is rounded (taken from a parameter in the profile type) + a list of profile types which should be taken from the 2 lists above.
If "Is Rounded Profile" is checked then "Profile Type" should be binded to roundProfileTypeNames list, otherwise (unchecked) it should be binded to rectProfileTypeNames.
Currently, I was only able to bind all rows to the same list (roundProfileTypeNames OR rectProfileTypeNames).
This is my datagrid in xaml file:


<DataGrid Name="profilePropsGrid" Width="500" CanUserReorderColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" CanUserAddRows="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Profile Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ProfileName, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="true" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Is Rounded Profile?" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsRound}" Checked="IsRoundChecked" Unchecked="IsRoundUnchecked" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" Header="Profile Type" x:Name="ProfileType" 
             SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ProfileType, Mode=TwoWay}"  
            DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ProfileType}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>



And this is a snippet from my xaml.cs file:
bridgeProfileList = new List<ProfileItem>();

foreach (Element elem in framingPipeTypesCol) // Iterating through all framing pipe types in Revit
{
    ProfileItem ep = new ProfileItem()
    {
        ProfileName = elem.Name,
        ProfileElement = elem
    };
    IList<Parameter> pipe_shape_circle = elem.GetParameters("Pipe Shape_Circle");
    if (pipe_shape_circle.Count > 0)
    {
        int pipe_shape = pipe_shape_circle[0].AsInteger();
        if (pipe_shape == 0)
        {
            ep.IsRound = false;
            //ProfileType.ItemsSource = rectProfileTypeNames;

        }
        if (pipe_shape == 1)
        {
            ep.IsRound = true;
            //ProfileType.ItemsSource = roundProfileTypeNames;

        }
    }
    bridgeProfileList.Add(ep);
    Debug.WriteLine(elem.Name);
}
profilePropsGrid.ItemsSource = bridgeProfileList;
ProfileType.ItemsSource = roundProfileTypeNames;

So, basically, I am trying to bind between the "Is Rounded Profile?" checkbox to the Profile Type ComboBox list. so if user checks / unchecks this checkbox - then a different list will appear in the combobox.
Any hint would be appreciated :)
[EDIT 1:]
This is my ProfileItem class:
internal class ProfileItem
{
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public bool IsRound { get; set; }
    public string ProfileType { get; set; }
    public Element ProfileElement { get; set; }
}

strong text  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/0z2jA.png

Just because you have data in a given shape does not mean you need to present that direct to your UI. Translate it into something suits your UI better. Bind that.

I have a ProfileItem class (edited now in my initial post) which populates the DataGrid rows. @Andy, can you please give me some more concrete actions to do in my code as I am new to WPF? Thanks.

Answered the identical question in the Revit API discussion forum thread on binding different lists to different rows in DataGrid.

That is absolutely correct - but since I couldn't reach to a solution yet and the question is much more WPF oriented rather than Revit oriented - I was trying to get more opinions on stackoverflow.
